# Is there any way to have PostgreSQL not collapse punctuation and spaces when collating using a language?

Tags: linux, macos, postgresql, collation

From what I understand, PostgreSQL delegates collation to the strcoll() function of underlying operating system, and apparently most (if not all) Linux installations take advantage of the fact that punctuation and spaces can be optionally collapsed when collating in UTF-8.

For example, I have a database in Postres 9.2 on CentOS 6.4 with

```
ENCODING='UTF8'
LC_COLLATE='en_US.UTF8'
LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF8'
```

and you run the query

```
select * from (values('abc'),('ABC'),('Abc'),('...ABc'),('a BC')) x order by 1;
```

The results are

```
abc
a BC
Abc
...ABc
ABC
```

Mac OS X seems to honor punctuation and spaces but then uses a POSIX/C style sort. A similar database with the same settings on OS X returns

```
...ABc
ABC
Abc
a BC
abc
```

Regardless of the operating system, I would expect a proper collation to return (and the [ICU Demo Project](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=en_US&d_=en&x=col) shows)

```
...ABc
a BC
abc
Abc
ABC
```

Is there any way to get Postgres installs on any operating system, but particularly Linux, to observe proper collation in the style of ICU?

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, Postgres relies on the operating system to provide collation, and there's little Postgres can do about how things get collated beyond hooking directly into ICU.

Doing so has been a recurring discussion topic over the years, but is not a trivial task:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:ICU

Comment: One option I've considered is creating an index using a language that collates properly, perhaps Java. Are there any insights or caveats about that?

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but there likely is a way to create a custom type, e.g. ICUString, and to cook up a BTree index on it. It's a lot of work, though.